# What determines the magnitude of force of an electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Let's assume that there is an electromagnet with $B = 1 T$ , what is the magnitude of the force it could generate on other dipoles equal to it's surface area? Can the magnitude of force (in newtons) be determined from $B$?

Comment: What matters is not the size but the dipole moment. The dipole moment is proportional to the current, the number of turns of wire, and the area. If you treat it as a dipole-dipole interaction (which I think is only appropriate in the far-field limit), then what matters is the product of the two dipole moments, the inverse cube of the distance, and the orientations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole%E2%80%93dipole_interaction If they're not far from each other, then I suspect the problem is much more complicated, although there may be heuristics.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the field is important for attracting force.  Dipole field force varies as the inverse cube of the distance.  Beyond that, a sharp edge or a point will have huge field divergence.  Magnetically permeable bodies will be sucked in, riding the divergence.  Note the pole pattern in refrigerator magnets and channel magnets.  For a given total field, one can be clever with addition and subtraction re Halbach arrays.

Comment: Would the size of the solenoid/magnet matter? I mean, if it was possible to make a $1 Tesla$ electromagnet that acts on a extremely small gap, what values of force would be expect?

Answer (score 0):

As @Uncle-Al said, it depends on shape distance etc. I remember, however, a standard exam question. Assume you have the electromagnet with area $A$ and you want to lift an object that can be magnetized. If the object is flat and can "absorb" all the magnetic flux you can calculate the force. What you actually calculate is the pressure. 
The pressure is given by the energy density in the gap (plate capacitor geometry, note that energy density and pressure have the same units). With the according area you get the force. But this is only that "simple" in this very special case. In general you cannot calculate the force only knowing that you have 1 T (not even saying where this 1 T are actually measured).

Comment: + 1, nice answer. I have a few questions in your line of expertise with no/poor answers, take a look at my [profile](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/104372/user104372?tab=questions&sort=newest) if you care to reply

Answer (score 0):

The force does not depend directly on the magnetic field of the magnet; it depends on the gradient of the magnetic field.

The magnetic potential energy of a magnetic dipole in a magnetic field is 
$$U = -\vec{m} \cdot \vec{B}$$
where $\vec{m}$ is the magnetic dipole moment.

The force exerted by the field is
$$\vec{F} = \nabla (\vec{m} \cdot \vec{B})$$

Of course the $\vec{B}$ here is the B-field *at the dipole*, so will depend on the field geometry and distance from your magnet.